# visual studio 2013 symbol issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, symbols

I'm new to visual studio and c#. I'm working on a database program using entity framework and everything was fine until yesterday. Suddenly the program wouldn't run after being compiled. I noticed some errors in Outpot:

```
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\spect_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FinancialInstitutionManagement\financialinstitutionmanagement\bin\Debug\financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x1f4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x964 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1210 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\spect_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FinancialInstitutionManagement\financialinstitutionmanagement\bin\Debug\financialinstitutionmanagement.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\spect_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FinancialInstitutionManagement\financialinstitutionmanagement\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

I have no idea why this happened . Also right clicking on EntityFramework.dll in Modules window and selecting Symbol Load Information didn't work. . After some googling i decided to use an alternative symbol server to see if it works. I used JetBrains dotPeek and chached symbols in a different directory. This time the Modules window showed me all symbols are loaded except:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll Yes N/A Symbols not loaded.     7   12.00.21005.1   10/5/2013 11:48 AM  02290000-0229A000   [2368] financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe    [1] financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe
```

after right clicking and selecting Symbol Load Information it says 'Symbols loaded.' on symbol status. But the program won't run. Anybody had the same problem? How can i fix this?

p.s
sorry for poor english

Edit:

I get no errors after compiling just this Output:

```
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\spect_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FinancialInstitutionManagement\financialinstitutionmanagement\bin\Debug\financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0xbb4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xccc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\spect_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FinancialInstitutionManagement\financialinstitutionmanagement\bin\Debug\financialinstitutionmanagement.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: financialinstitutionmanagement.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\spect_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FinancialInstitutionManagement\financialinstitutionmanagement\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x1a6c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

Edit 2:
By the way i couldn't figure out what caused the problem after all. Here is a quick workaround if anybody had the same problem, check Just My Code in debugging options and uncheck all symbol servers. This should work.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean but i emptied debug and release folder but still program is not running. i also moved every code to a new project but it didn't help either

Comment: The program not running is unrelated to the symbols not being found (which is perfectly normal for third-party DLLs like EntityFramework, by the way). The symbols are *only* used for debugging. What error are you getting? How do you know your program isn't working as expected?

Comment: I just edited the question, as said, i just get the mentioned output.